# Selecting first element using `first of type` css selector selects multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementsbyclassname, queryselector

I have this website

https://www.sirved.com/restaurant/essex-ontario-canada/dairy-freez/1/menus/3413655

I tried selecting the first element using

```
document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-wrapper:first-of-type')
```

But this returns me multiple nodes

```
NodeList(2) [div.swiper-wrapper, div.swiper-wrapper]
```

Basically I was trying to get the `img` tag inside the element, currently I am doing it in 3 statements. The only thing that changes below is `('swiper-slide') : [0],[1],[2]`

```
document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-wrapper')[0].getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide')[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src')
document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-wrapper')[0].getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide')[1].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src')
document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-wrapper')[0].getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide')[2].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src')
```

I want to combine the above statements into one using `querySelectorAll`. I know how to do the same using multiple statements. But I was looking for a CSS_SELECTOR approach to get all 3 img elements.

This is what I tried, which is wrong

```
imgList = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-wrapper:nth-of-type(1) > .swiper-slide > img')
```

How can I get all 3 `img` using `querySelectorAll`

Comment: If you have multiple `.swiper-wrappe` that are the first element within their parent `:first-of-type` will select all of them. if you are 100% sure that the element you want comes first in the markup use `querySelector()` instead *(equivlent to `querySelectorAll()[0]`)*. Why are you relying on CSS inside javascript ? doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: is it not possible to select the first instance of class say 'ABC' using query selector itself? @Zohini

Comment: I daresay no, a selector selects **all** occurrences that matches it, there is no avoiding it unless being as specific as needed, there is `:first-of-selected` for example. You can chain `querySelector` However  `querySelector('.swiper-wrapper:first-of-type').querySelectorAll('img')`

Answer (score 0):

- `:first-of-type` pseudo-class reperesent the first element of its type ***among a group of sibling elements***.
- `document.querySelectorArr()` - always returns ***a NodeList of the document elements*** that match the specified group of selectors.

If I understand you correctly, you want to select all the img tags inside the first swiper-wrapper container.

Basically all you need is this

```
document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-wrapper:first-of-type img')
```

```js
let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.a:first-of-type p');

for (let node of nodes) {
  node.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```css
.a:first-of-type p {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <p>inside first .a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <p>inside first .a</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <p>inside second .a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <p>inside second .a</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this does not answer my question, please read my question above